# Document found with _search but not with GET

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a single machine elastic search server (8 shards but all hosted at the same machine). Index contains 7 million documents. We do not specify any custom routing when indexing the documents. We are using Elastic search version 1.2.

The problem is that we are unable to retrieve many of our documents using GET , . However using search?_id: we are able to retrieve all of those documents.

We are also successful in retrieving a document by specifying routing parameter (with different values (1,2,3,...) ) with GET.

With previous version, i.e. Elastic Search 1.0.3, we did not have that problem.

Any suggestions for resolution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in Elasticsearch 1.2.0 that causes this specific behavior. It's due to a routing bug that was introduced in 1.2.0:

> There was a routing bug in Elasticsearch 1.2.0 that could have a
>   number of bad side effects on the cluster. Possible side effects
>   include:
>
> - documents that were indexed prior to the upgrade to 1.2.0 may not be    accessible via get. A search would find these documents, but not
>     a    direct get of the document by ID.
> - documents that were updated after the upgrade to 1.2.0 may be    duplicated, with one copy from pre-1.2.0 and a second copy updated
>     since the upgrade to 1.2.0.
> - if a document is duplicated as above, and versioning is in use, the    document added after the upgrade to 1.2.0 will have its version
>     reset.

ES is advising everyone to upgrade to 1.2.1 immediately. No word yet on how to resolve what appears to be index corruption introduced by using 1.2.0 to insert or update. Full details here:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/elasticsearch-1-2-1-released/